# Indpu with width:100% inside a div with position relative and width 40px has 100px

Tags: css, ckeditor, width

The main idea is kind of like this I have a div with position relative and set width (40px) and an input with `width:100%`. The problem is that instead of 40px with on input its width is 100px.

As you can see in the last image the input appears to be unfinished.

I can't figure it why so here are some prints with the structure:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any chance you could post a link to a page? Your description, complete with images, is quite good but this looks like the type of problem where most people would find it easier to hack away with a tool like Firebug.

Comment: Unfortunately the site is hosted on a virtual machine. So I can't provide you with a link to a working copy. The print screens are from firebug as you can see... and for the rest of encapsulating elements... all have position relative and width 100% table has display:block... I. No other properties (except of course font-size, color, etc... witch are not exactly relevant to this problem).

Comment: If you really can't upload a test case, then you could upload a `.zip` containing the relevant parts of the site. It's not great, but it might help your question get answered.

Comment: I would have to upload the whole site (zend+smarty+ckeditor) to work (because the window with the problem is dynamically generated)... and unfortunately I can't (trust me I understand the need for a working copy and I would ask the same thing if I were you).

Comment: Well, the first thing I would try is adding some margin and padding to every element in sight, to see if it made the right edge visible.

Comment: Tried already... It does not become visible. I checked the layout tab and the input width is 108px. I really don't know why. There is no line that specify that checked 3 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to explicitely give the input a width of 40px, not just to its parent element. Also give it a display: block;

```
.cka_dialog_ui_input_text input {
  display: block;/* fixes some errors */
  width: 36px;/* 40 - 2x2px border*/
  padding: 0;/* just for testing*/
}
```

Comment: Ok... it works like this. Everything looks fine tough I was prefering not to style the input itself. There are some ramifications but... I try to work around them if no other ideas can be found.